# Optional strongly typed compilers

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there any language/framework for generating JavaScript with support for optional strongly typed code?

Something that would allow writing code as not strongly typed, but with an option to run checks and/or compile a report about where it would fail if it were strongly typed.

As a side question, is it possible to make TypeScript turn off its strongly typed enforcement?

Comment: how about [flow](http://flowtype.org)?

Comment: @NitzanTomer that's very interesting, I'm reading it now :) Never heard of it before. But then again, that's why I asked the question :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want a mix of typed and non-typed code, then [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) does have the `any` type (which is what stuff is if not otherwise specified).

Comment: Writing in TypeScript using `any` means you end up with the code that cannot be checked.